# Automator workflow/service or Applescript for looped edits in Preview

Tags: automator, preview, graphics, services, image-editing

I was originally trying this with Automator, but if someone can guide me to accomplishing this easier with Applescript then feel free, though i haven't worked with it before. I'm trying to get the Crop Images and/or Scale Images actions running in a Preview service. I've saved a workflow with some Watch Me Do actions, and I'm able to run the service from Preview -> Services. But if i add either of these actions it skips the Watch Me Do actions and hangs. It seems as if these built-in actions are not using the open image that the service is already processing. How can I include these actions in my workflow? It seems Automator ignores anything i do with the area selection tools (like the "rectangular selection") so i have to use these built-in actions.

If this can be done only in an application or workflow, but not a service in the way i describe, that's fine as long as i can have the watch me do actions and scale/crop actions done on the same file while it's still open, and then loop at the end so i can have the same edits done on the same file multiple times.

**update**: i don't necessarily need the WMD actions included if it's not feasible in Automator. I was told on Apple Discussions Forum that "Generally speaking, Automator works on files passed to actions and/or on applications. In your particular case, you can use Automator to crop/scale/etc. images, but it's mostly a closed process once the Automator workflow launches. Trying to use Automator to performs actions on an image already buffered into an application's memory space isn't going to work."

I could potentially use built-in actions like Crop, Scale, and others if i can get them to work on a single designated file and repeated the actions in a Loop. someone suggested using red menace's Dispense Item Incrementally action (http://automator.us/leopard/downloads/) so i'm going to give this a try.

**update 2**: unfortunately, i checked this out and from what it says it's intended for multiple items to be processed where i just need the workflow to process 1 image file continually until i stop the loop so the selected edits repeat within the 1 file. here are some basic actions i'm trying to get started with:

(1) get specified finder items (2) copy finder items (3) scale images (4) crop images (5) loop

The problem is that i want to loop only actions 3 & 4, but the loop starts over at 1 and creates a new file each time it loops. Can i create 2 workflows where the 2nd one (containing actions 3/4/5) starts when the first (containing 1/2) ends so only the 2nd workflow is looped? I'm not sure how to tell the 2nd one to start when the first ends though. Do i just set the input of the 2nd to use the 1st workflow file?

Originally i had this setup solely as WMD (watch me do) actions but Automator won't record the selection tool. if i can get the selection tool recorded then i can keep it as a WMD based workflow. Acorn (for crop/scale i believe) & Extra Suites (Applescript app for recording the mouse click & draw) were apps i saw mentioned on other posts that came up on google searches which might be able to help accomplish this workflow or script.

thanks

Comment: is there a message in Automator for why?

Comment: In the toolbar's spinning gear icon it would hang @ Cropping Image 3/5, though i had only 1 image open in Preview. I also recall hearing the system error sound i had selected in Sound prefs. I was told on the Apple Discussion forum that "Generally speaking, Automator works on files passed to actions and/or on applications. In your particular case, you can use Automator to crop/scale/etc. images, but it's mostly a closed process once the Automator workflow launches. Trying to use Automator to performs actions on an image already buffered into an application's memory space isn't going to work."